# SSRS parameter two values joined

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a dataset query parameter with specific values (A, B, C, D, E, F, G). I would like to have values B and C in one parameter value (B/C), and the rest of values normally. So basically, my list would need to be: A, B/C, D, E, F, G). Do you have any suggestions? I'm thinking of expression on parameter, but I'm not sure where and how to put it there. Or maybe it is better to have dataset filter? Any help would be appreciated, I'm stuck.

I tried IIF in parameter value expression, but it doesn't work. 
This is the code in parameter value expression:

```
    =iif(INSTR(Parameters!Modalitet.Value,"B") > 0 OR INSTR(Parameters!Modalitet.Value,"C") > 0, Parameters!Modalitet.Value, "B/C")
```

This is the where clause from dataset parameter query:

```
    WHERE  (ExDev.Modalitet IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D',  'E', 'F', 'G'))
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how the parameter will be used in your dataset, as this will decide how best to solve your problem. Give an brief actual code example if possible.

Comment: You should be able to edit the list of available values without any problem.

Comment: The parameter is used to filter the results by user choice of particular value. The issue is how to put two values in one user choice, so that the user can choose values B and C joined. Multi-select is not a good solution for my customer. Right now I use additional query for the parameter, but I can hard-code the values if that can be a better solution.

Comment: If the parameter is used in your dataset query, can you show the relevant part of the code (probably the WHERE clause)

Comment: The parameter query part of Hannover's answer solved my issue, I didn't need to use filter expression as I configured the parameter to use the parameter query. I have another question now as I have cascaded parameters, so my Parameter B is dependent on Parameter A. I configured the parameter B query to use Parameter A, but when I choose B/C value from Parameter A, Parameter B is empty. Do I need to reconfigure parameter B query regarding the changes in parameter A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would combine the two values in your parameter query and then use INSTR in the filter. Since the **B\C** has both letters, the INSTR will find either ( INSTR("B/C", "C") ).

**Parameter Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN ExDev.Modalitet IN ('B', 'C') THEN 'B\C' ELSE ExDev.Modalitet AS Modalitet 
FROM ExDev
```

**Filter Expression:**

```
=IIF(INSTR(Parameters!Modalitet.Value, ExDev.Modalitet) > 0, 1, 0)
```

and set the Type to **Integer** and Value to **1**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will do like that and let you know about the results.

Comment: I get incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. When I delete 'AS Modalitet', I get the same error near the word "FROM'. So, I suppose something is wrong in distinct or case syntax.

Comment: I found out  what was the problem. The correct sintax would be: SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN ExDev.Modalitet IN ('B', 'C') THEN 'B\C' ELSE ExDev.Modalitet end AS Modalitet 
FROM ExDev